# My SQL statment is correct but still returns an error

Tags: php, sql

On my website I try to take a few info and add them to my database but ever since I changed the date to datetime the whole SQL statment doesn't work anymore.

I looked everywhere online and no one else seem to have the same problem I might just have missed something but the SQL statment looks correct to me.

```php
public function addTimeLine($typeOfPost,$post,$idImage,$numberImage){
    $post = addslashes($post);
    $typeOfPost = addslashes($typeOfPost);
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $query = "INSERT INTO `time_line` ( `special_note`, `type`, `id_image`, `number_image`, `dates`) VALUES ( '".$post."', '".$typeOfPost."', ".$idImage.", ".$numberImage.", '".$date."')";
    $ps = $this->_db->prepare($query);
    $ps->execute();
}
```

and it gives me this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1, '2019-07-12 16:29:58')' at line 1

Comment: `'".$typeOfPost."', ".$idImage.",` see , ur missing some `''`

Comment: `echo $query` and check it directly to phpmyadmin.you will definitely find the syntex error.just do it

Comment: You are munging strings into your query string.  How could you possible know if the result is correct SQL or not?  Learn how to use parameters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not using prepared statements correctly. You need to use placeholders and then pass the values in the `execute`

```
public function addTimeLine($typeOfPost, $post, $idImage, $numberImage) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $query = "INSERT INTO `time_line` ( `special_note`, `type`, `id_image`, `number_image`, `dates`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";
    $ps = $this->_db->prepare($query);
    $ps->execute([
        $post,
        $typeOfPost,
        $idImage,
        $numberImage
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing quotes, try the following:

```sql
$query = "INSERT INTO time_line(`special_note`, `type`, `id_image`, `number_image`, `dates`) VALUES ({$post},{$typeOfPost},{$idImage},{$numberImage},{$date})";
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer, but it didn't work ):

Comment: @Dharman you're completely right, I totally forgot that part :| I use to work with Doctrine which does the needed to avoid SQL injection and some other attacks